# Separating the time from a date from a string

Tags: linux, bash, datetime, pattern-matching

I have some files that contain in their name the following string: "20171011095942", which is the date and time "2017/10/11 09:59:42".

```
text_text_20171011095937_155.DAT.gz
text_text_20171011095942_156.DAT.gz
```

I need to select all files that start at the hour 09 and put them in another folder. If I use the command:

```
date -d '20171011095942' +'%R'
```

It says "invalid date". How can I separate the time from that string so I can then select only those files?
Thank you!

Comment: Is the file-name format fixed? `text_text_20171011095942_156.DAT.gz`? can you give us some actual examples? i.e. does the date part start after 2nd `_` ?

Comment: Yes, the name format is fixed. The only difference in the name of the files is the sequence of numbers as they point to another time and date and the numbers that define the file number ( 155,156 ). The date part always starts after the second "_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **find** + **mv** commands:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*_2017101109[0-9]{4}_.*\.gz" -exec mv {} dest_dir/ \;
```

---

In the above command change `dest_dir` to your *"another folder"*.

`.*_2017101109[0-9]{4}_.*\.gz` - regex pattern to match all filenames containing the needed sequence.

- `.*` - matches any character(s)
- `_2017101109` - matches the crucial numeric sequence (`<year><month><day><hours>`)
- `[0-9]{4}_` - ensures that the above mentioned sequence if followed by 4 digits which point to `<minutes><seconds>`
- `\.gz` - ensures a file extension to be `.gz`

Comment: This is great, thank you! Just a small question. I understand that this command searches in the current directory, for files. You used the "-regextype posix-egrep" so you can use the extended regular expressions, but I don't really understand the regular expression you used inside the regex. Could you please explain it a bit?